# Cocoa Scripting: "whose clause" cannot access certain properties

Tags: applescript, cocoa-scripting

I am working on making my application scriptable. I struggle with the "whose" filter clause.

I want to make this work, but while `name` can be used, `country` can not:

```
tell application "myapp"
    get every city whose name is "Berlin" -- works
    get every city whose country is "Germany" -- error -1700 (Can’t make country into type specifier)
end tell
```

The relevant parts of the sdef look like this:

```
<class name="application" code="capp">
    <cocoa class="NSApplication"/>
    <element type="city">
        <cocoa key="allCities"/>
        <accessor style="index"/>
    </element>
    <class name="city" code="Citi" plural="cities">
        <cocoa class="ScriptableCity"/>
        <property name="name" code="pnam" type="text" access="r">
            <cocoa key="name"/>
        </property>
        <property name="country" code="Ctry" type="text" access="r">
            <cocoa key="country"/>
        </property>
    </class>
```

What must I do to make `country` work with "whose" as well? Apparently, the "whose" clause wants a type specifier, not a property name, but I can't make sense of this.

I have implemented `indicesOfObjectsByEvaluatingObjectSpecifier:`, but that only gets called for `name`, not for `country`.

Comment: Consider that you don't have to specify explicitly the cocoa key for a property with the same name. But I recommend to separate always the property of the model from the scripting property by using a category for each cocoa class to avoid  terminology clashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I had it all wrong. My program code is fine. The issue is caused by the fact that I also have a *class* named `country`. So AppleScript, looking at the outmost scope for the identifier first, finds the ***class*** `country` and tries to use that for the comparison. Had the error message included the word "class", this would have been easier to detect, probably.

There are now two solutions:

1. Rename the property in the Sdef so that it does not clash with the class name any more, e.g. to `country name`.
2. Use `of it` in order to change the scope for the lookup of the identifier, like this:

   ```
   get every city whose country of it is "Germany"
   ```

It is also important to make sure that if the same property name is used in several classes, they all use the same 4-char type code. Otherwise this problem can surface as well.